# Transposing a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

How can we write a plsql code which transposes values of Table A into Table B.

Table A

```
rec_id ||  col1  || col2  ||  col3
   2        val1     val2       val3
   3        val4     val5       val6
```

desired output in table B

Table B

```
 rec_id   ||   type  ||   value
 2                  col1         val1
 2                  col2         val2
 2                   col3         val3
 3                  col4         val5
 3                  col5         val5
 3                   col6         val6
```

only if val1 or val2 or val3 is not null. if any of the value is null then there should no rec in table B. For example if val2 is null then

```
    rec_id   ||   type  ||   value
       2         col1         val1
       2         col3         val3
```

Comment: . . I'm not 100% sure I understand the `NULL` condition.  Is the intention merely to filter out `NULL` values?

Comment: Yes if there is any NULL value for any column in table A then it should not appear in table B in the type and value columns

Comment: What is "it"?  The row?  The column?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 11.1 and above, you can use `UNPIVOT`. I added some test data to show the treatment of `NULL`. (Remember that in Oracle, an empty string, `''`, is the same as `NULL`.)

```
with
     table_a ( rec_id, col1, col2, col3 ) as (
       select 2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' from dual union all
       select 3, 'val4', ''    , 'val6' from dual union all
       select 8, ''    , ''    , ''     from dual
     )
--  end of test data; query begins below this line
select *
from   table_a
unpivot ( value for type in ( col1 as 'col1', col2 as 'col2', col3 as 'col3') )
;


REC_ID  TYPE  VALUE
------  ----  -----
     2  col1  val1
     2  col2  val2
     2  col3  val3
     3  col1  val4
     3  col3  val6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `union all` (among other methods):

```
select rec_id, 'col1' as type, col1 as value from t where col1 is not null union all
select rec_id, 'col2' as type, col2 as value from t where col2 is not null union all
select rec_id, 'col3' as type, col3 as value from t where col3 is not null;
```

You seem to want to eliminate both rows and columns where any `NULL` appears:

```
select rec_id, type, value
from (select t.*,
             (case when count(*) over (partition by type) = count(value) over (partition by type)
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as no_null_type,
             (case when count(*) over (partition by recid) = count(value) over (partition by recid)
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as no_null_recid
      from (select rec_id, 'col1' as type, col1 as value from t union all
            select rec_id, 'col2' as type, col2 as value from t union all
            select rec_id, 'col3' as type, col3 as value from t
           ) t
     ) t
where no_null_type = 1 and no_null_recid = 1;
```

In Oracle 12c, you can use lateral joins:

```
select t.rec_id, x.type, x.value
from t cross apply
     (select 'col1' as type, col1 as value from dual union all
      select 'col2' as type, col2 as value from dual union all
      select 'col3' as type, col3 as value from dual
     ) x
where value is not null;
```

This has the advantage of only scanning the table once.  You can apply similar logic for the removal of `NULL`s.

Comment: does this query cover the null condition?

Comment: @mathguy . . . The OP appears to want both rows and columns removed, so it uses the same method for both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm know for fact that the table name you showed is not actual table that you want run the query on and it might have more than 3 columns.

So I came up with a PLSQL procedure(if you want in sql then other answer will help you)

```
    DECLARE
      SQLSELECT VARCHAR2(1000);
      SQLINSERT VARCHAR2(1000);
      TYPE TCur IS REF CURSOR;
        cur TCur;
      TYPE TRec IS RECORD (ID INT,
                           COL_VAL VARCHAR2(20));
      v_rec TRec;
    BEGIN
      FOR rec IN
      (SELECT column_name
        FROM all_tab_columns
        WHERE table_name = 'TABLEA')
      LOOP
      IF (rec.column_name <> 'REC_ID') THEN
        SQLSELECT:= 'SELECT ID,'||rec.column_name||' column_name FROM TABLEA 
                     where '||rec.column_name||' is not null';
        OPEN cur FOR SQLSELECT;
        LOOP
          FETCH cur INTO v_rec;
          EXIT WHEN cur%notfound;
         -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rec.ID||' '||v_rec.COL_VAL||' '||rec.column_name);
          SQLINSERT:= 'INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES(:1, :2, :3)';
          --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLINSERT);
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLINSERT USING v_rec.ID,v_rec.COL_VAL,rec.column_name;
        END LOOP;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    END;
```

Here you have to change the `TABLEA` with your table name and `REC_ID` according to your table id, you have to create the destination table before running the code and replace `TABLEB` with your destination table name. It will also covers null condition. Commented statement is helpful while debugging the code